# Tiene desventajas usar muchos paneles?

Tags: java

'Tiene desventajas usar muchos paneles?Habia escuchado que eran muy pesados y por eso tengo un poco de miedo en usar multiples paneles,queria saber si esto era cierto

Comment: Hola Santiago, aunque esta pregunta es sobre programación, ha sido reportada por la comunidad como de baja calidad y basada en opiniones. Tal y como está redactada, es muy amplia y algo subjetiva. Para hacerla más concreta y objetiva sería bueno que la editaras para añadir algunas cosas: cita fuentes, el motivo de la cuestión (¿pesados a nivel de memoria, de tamaño al generar la aplicación, de lentitud...?), añade algo de código, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los menos como sea posible para posicionar tus objetos a tu gusto.
Los suficientes para conseguirlo.

También es una ventaja el conocimiento de todos los layouts, su utilidad y el conocimiento de poder crear layouts a medida. Esto puede llegar a reducir el número de paneles.

Comment: Gracias amigo,justo estoy batallando con esto de los layouts y por eso se me ocurrio la pregunta jajaja